# SQL (Postgres) how to query many to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, typeorm

I have company and user as many to many relationship.
A company can have many users and a user can have many companies.

I have the following tables:

**Company** (id, name)

**User** (id, name)

**User_Company** (userId, companyId)

How do I search by company's name and by a user?

Eg. Search company where name = "Apple" and userId = 1

Example result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "User 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "User 5"
            }
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "My Apple",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "User 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "User 2"
            }
            
        ]
    }
]
```

Note: I'm using TypeOrm with Postgresql

Comment: So, what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing? Please update your question with what you've managed to write on your own

Answer (score 0):

```
create table company (id integer primary key, name varchar(50));
create table users (id integer primary key, name varchar(50));
create table user_company (userid integer not null, companyid integer not null);

insert into company (id, name) values
(1, 'Apple'),
(3, 'My Apple');

insert into users (id, name) values
(1, 'User 1'),
(2, 'User 2'),
(3, 'User 3'),
(4, 'User 4'),
(5, 'User 5');

insert into user_company (userid, companyid) values
(1, 1),
(1, 3),
(5, 1),
(2, 3);

select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(jx)))
from (
  select id, name,
    (
      select array_to_json(array_agg(distinct u))
      from (
        select id, name
        from user_company, users
        where user_company.companyid = company.id
          and users.id = user_company.userid
      ) u
    ) as users
  from company
) jx;
```

It gives :

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Apple","users":[{"id":1,"name":"User 1"},{"id":5,"name":"User 5"}]},{"id":3,"name":"My Apple","users":[{"id":1,"name":"User 1"},{"id":2,"name":"User 2"}]}]
```